# Open music files with different application from dash?

Tags: 12.04, unity-dash, music

I was wondering if it is possible to click on music files in Dash and have them open with a specific application instead of them always opening with Rhythmbox?

Comment: You can set the default application based on file types. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I don't use Unity, but doesn't the Dash use whatever program the files are currently associated with? If so, right-click the music file (from your regular file manager), select Properties, look for "Open with..." or something, select the program you want from the list, and don't forget to tick the checkbox that reads "Use this program as default" (or something) if there's one, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the default application used for music files by going to **System Settings > Details > Default Applications** and then replacing Rhythmbox with whatever media player you prefer.

(You can also leave Rhythmbox on your dock so you can launch it when you prefer to use it instead)

Comment: Here are pics http://www.howtogeek.com/117709/how-to-change-your-default-applications-on-ubuntu-4-ways/

Comment: I have tried that cause I have audacious as my default for music files and Rhythmbox opens when I click on a music file from the music lens

Comment: If you're having trouble with a particular audio format just right click on that particular song in your file manager, choose Properties > Open With and set it as the default manually.

Comment: I have Audacious set as default in either instance but still when clicking a music file in the music lens in dash still continues to open Rhythmbox. I have set it to default to Audacious but have had no luck.

Comment: I would try uninstalling rhythmbox to see what launches from the dash.